# Lines tangent to the same conic

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

Consider two lines $l_1, l_2\subset \mathbb{R}P^2$ and a projective transformation $\phi:l_1\to l_2$. How do I show that each line constructed by joining a point $P\in l_1$ with its image $\phi(P)$ is tangent to the same conic.

I tried letting $l_1= \lambda [(1,0,0)]+\mu[(0,1,0)]$, which is allowed after a projective transformation, but how to I determine the coefficients of the conic?

Any help would be very welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that line $X\phi(X)$ envelopes a conic is a theorem due to Steiner (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_conic) in particular the 7th figure).

As your question is about finding the equation of this conic, here is an answer giving this equation, and as well, proving the theorem.

I begin by an illustration:

[image]

Let us assume WLOG that the first line is taken as the axis of abscissa, which means that all its ordinary points have coordinates $(x,0,1)$ (its point at infinity is $(x,0,0)$).

WLOG again we can assume that the homography takes the form:

$$X=(x,0,1) \mapsto  \ \phi(X)=(ax+c,dx+f,gx+k)\approx\underbrace{(\frac{ax+c}{gx+k},\frac{dx+f}{gx+k},1)}_{\text{for "ordinary" points}}\tag{1}$$

for some constants $a,c,d,f,g,k$.

We are going to establish that the conic curve enveloped by line $X\phi(X)$ has the equation

$$Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0\tag{2}$$

or said otherwise the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}A&B&D\\B&C&E\\D&E&F\end{pmatrix} \ \text{with} \ \begin{cases}A&=&d^2\\B&=&dk-ad-2fg\\C&=&(a-k)^2+4cg\\D&=&df\\E&=&af-fk-2cd\\F&=&f^2\end{cases}$$

Proof:

Due to (1), the equation of line $X\phi(X)$ can be written under the form of this determinant equal to 0:

$$\begin{vmatrix}x_0& (ax_0+c) &x&\\0&(dx_0+f)&y\\1&(gx_0+k)&1\end{vmatrix}=0$$

where $x_0$ is a parameter characterizing the straight line. Expanding:

$$x(dx_0+f)-y((ax_0+c)-x_0(gx_0+k))-x_0(dx_0+f)=0 \tag{3}$$

Now we are ready apply the standard method to find an envelope, i.e., differentiating (3) wrt parameter $x_0$ (see explanations in the appendix of one of my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1685509)):

$$dx-y(a-2gx_0-k)-2dx_0-f \implies x_0=\frac{f+ay-yk-dx}{2(gy-d)}\tag{4}$$

Plugging this expression of $x_0$ into (3), one obtains indeed the second degree equation (1).

Here is the Matlab program I have written for obtaining the figure:

```
    clear all;close all;hold on;axis([-4,4,-1,3])
    a=1;c=8;d=3;f=2;g=2;k=1
    for x=-4:0.2:4;
        plot([x,(a*x+c)/(g*x+k)],[0,(d*x+f)/(g*x+k)])
    end;
    A=d^2;
    B=-a*d+d*k-2*f*g;
    C=a^2-2*a*k+k^2+4*c*g;
    D=d*f;
    E=a*f-2*c*d-f*k;
    F=f^2;
    h=@(A,B,C,D,E,F,x,y)(A*x.^2+2*B*x.*y+C*y.^2+2*D*x+2*E*y+F);
    ez=ezplot(@(x,y)h(A,B,C,D,E,F,x,y))
```

Comment: thank you, you just increased my algebraic geometry grade! :)

Comment: Thanks for your thanks, I appreciate.

Comment: +1 for working this out explicitly.  There is a short analytic proof in Salmon's Conics, Article 329 (https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonconi08salmgoog/page/n322/mode/2up), but it presupposes a lot of earlier material.

Comment: @brainjam Thanks for this reference.

Comment: See also [V. Blåsjö 2009](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00283-008-9012-z).